# My rat is having an issue

Tags: veterinarian, rat

So the reason I haven't taken him to a vet till now is that I doubt the local vet is trained for rats.

I don't know what is the age of this rat. Since past about two months it is banking on the left side. Almost like it is trying to fall over to the left side. Its head is always tilted to the left and it walks like a drunk man, stumbling very often. Its sad to see him, and he  is my most dear rat. He's basically a very nice guy and I'd like to help him out.

Why could it be? Is it nutrition issue or something else? I feed him just the rat feed as prescribed by someone. Its getting worse. Need suggestions.

UPDATE : Google bard says it could be due to ear infection. Can I buy any drops off the market?

UPDATE: Night before last last night my rat seemed to be suffering, so I put some ear drops meant for humans [Salts: Ciprofloxacin (0.3% w/v) & Dexamethasone(0.1% w/v)] in his both ears. Next morning I took him to the doggy doc who refused to treat him saying he wouldn't know how to treat small animals. Since then I have just been giving him the same ear drops. He still banks to the left side but seems, I don't know, maybe more happy. At least the human ear drops haven't done any noticeable harm, yet. If anyone knows anything more on this let me know. I'm giving him the ear drops twice a day, morning and night. He struggles and shakes it off so maybe I end up putting in more than what I'd give a human just to be sure it goes in.

Comment: If it is indeed an ear infection (I have no idea) then ear drops for cats and dogs should probably help. Don't use plain water or the "all natural herbal" ear cleaners - those are mostly just chamomile tea and not suited to treat an infection. However, if the inner ear is infected, ear drops cannot reach it and are completely useless.

Comment: @Elmy ok would try to get some drops and see if it works.

Comment: @Elmy I updated my question, did some experiment with medicine, let me know if you don't like anything about it.